# Unable to install new package on debian armhf

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I got a debian 7.4 armhf that have been running for month without any problems. A few days ago I made some updates, and after that it seams that my dpkg doesn't work correctly any more.

When I try to install a new package using :

```
apt-get install packet_name
```

I get :

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
    packet_name 
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/58,4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 184 kB of additional disk space will be used.
/usr/bin/dpkg: 1: /usr/bin/dpkg: ��������������
�������
... loads more of � ...
������ E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (127)
```

I also get an error when trying to use dpkg directly :

```
dpkg -i package_name.deb
```

the error is :

```
/usr/bin/dpkg: line 1: $'\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377
\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377
\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377
\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377
\377\377\377\377\377\377

...Load more of \377...

\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377
\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377': command not found
```

I imagine that this error is liked to the last packages I updates but I don't even know hos to get the list of the updated packages without using dpkg.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This looks like data corruption due to a software or hardware bug. I recommend a memory test; I don't know what software to use on an armhf device (RPi?).

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by simply reinstalling the dpkg binarys. For the I downloaded the .deb package of dpkg and extracted it by hand. The I copied and pasted the binarys in the right place (/usr/bin).